# Spyware Removal - Total Security

Tags: spyware

I got wacked with the spyware "Total Security" which shows fake scans etc. What legit remover-tool can I use to get this out? All AV scanners refuse to remove it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what AV software are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of Malwarebytes Anti-Malware from [www.malwarebytes.org](http://www.malwarebytes.org).  Update its definitions and let it run a full scan.  It has handled every fake anti-virus/anti-spyware app that I have thrown at it with no problems.  Once you've got everything cleaned up, get a copy of Spybot Search & Destroy and use its immunize feature on a regular basis to help keep your PC protected.

Answer (score -1):

I'd also recommend installing at least one of the free anti-spyware tools in addition to av software.  My own favourite is spybot search and destroy but other people prefer ad-aware. If possible set it to scan on a schedule otherwise run it manually at least once a week.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

- http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-total-security.html

---

#### Total Security manual removal:

##### Kill processes:

```
tsc.exe Sc2C21UvvM.exe
```

##### Delete registry values:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\1FD92E3F7C34799BFB075C41DA05D1FE
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{D263FA6D-84CC-48A8-9AF6-C664362B7A5B}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{D263FA6D-84CC-48A8-9AF6-C664362B7A5B}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run "1FD92E3F7C34799BFB075C41DA05D1FE"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Security Center "AntiVirusOverride" = "1"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Security Center "FirewallOverride" = "1"
```

##### Unregister DLLs:

```
winsource.dll
```

##### Delete files:

```
tsc.exe
Sc2C21UvvM.exe
winsource.dll
TSC.lnk
Help.lnk
Registration.lnk
Uninstall TSC.lnk
```

##### Delete directories:

```
c:\Program Files\TSC
%UserProfile%\Start Menu\TSC
c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Uninstall
```

---

**Note**: If you're unable to do some of the steps above... boot up in SAFE MODE and try the steps again.

Comment: I tried this earlier. This seems to be a new variant.